# convert MySql Query to yii framework Query system

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I want to convert this SQL query to CDbCriteria format in Yii framework so I can use it in Yii:

```
SELECT title FROM project WHERE ((title like 'to %') or (title like ' % to %') or (title like '% to'));
```

Yiiframework CDbCriteria Description Link is as below:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria

Comment: Just a heads-up: the above query will ignore records with only `'to'` as the title. You might want to include a condition for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->select = "title";
$criteria->condition = "((title like ':to%') or (title like ' % :to %') or (title like '% :to'))";
$criteria->params = array(':to' => 'to');

$model = new Project;
$models = $model->findAll($criteria);
```

Comment: CDbCritera should be CDbCriteria

Answer (score 4):

also you can try this

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->select = "title";
$criteria->compare('title',' to ',true);

$model = new Project;
$models = $model->findAll($criteria);
```

Comment: This works only if you add a 3th param to compare with value 'true'

Comment: CDbCritera should be CDbCriteria